# Installer vs. zip or executable exe?

Tags: installation, compression, exe

In most of the games and programs you download, you just get the installer.
Some .exe files can be ran straightly, though (it's probably cause they don't have much source files to extract, huh?).

I was wondering, what's the difference between an installer, that just extracts the files, and a zip (rar, iso..) file, that you could download ,just depending on your internet speed, in up to few seconds. And where does a, maybe 200mb, installer fetch the, let's say 5gb of, files, offline?

I've never heard about this, and I'm learning to program, so I'd appreciate if you could answer me properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're really asking is:

## How does an installer work?

A bit of background.

[image: Apple }{, Jobs' gift to humanity.]

In the Before Times, man did not have such things as "installers." Software was run directly off of floppy disks (and none of that rigid 3.5" crap, I'm talking disks that *flopped*), like God intended.

Then came the first home computers with persistent hard drives. For the first time, it made sense to copy a program off a disk and have it stick around.

But programs still worked the way "portable" applications do today: you copied them as-is and ran them as-is.

Then operating systems began to get more complicated.

[image: The Great Satan?]

Windows introduced this notion of a *registry*: a central location where program and operating system configuration could be stored. Software authors began using this registry. Its arcane architecture and user-hostile editing utility (the infamous `regedit.exe`) made it the perfect place to store *shareware* information -- how many days you have left on your trial, for example.

This happened around the same time that programs began to be too large to fit -- uncompressed -- on a single floppy disk. A way was needed to split a program onto multiple disks. Since it wasn't very user-friendly to require the user to have e.g. a ZIP extractor installed (remember, this was before ubiquitous Internet), Windows programs began to be shipped with installers. You can think of these as basically portable versions of WinZIP whose sole purpose was to reassemble and extract a compressed file.

[image: auuuuughhhhhhh]

These days, installers serve a number of other purposes:

- providing a convenient user interface
- prompting the user to accept a click-through end-user license agreement (EULA)
- prompting the user for CD keys (though this is being phased out for many systems in favor of digital distribution)
- asking the user to register their software

and so on. They may also serve as DRM vehicles, validating CDs and decrypting data to prevent villainous individuals (yarr) from brrreakin' ye olde DMCA.

At their heart, they aren't any more complex than in the Windows 95 days -- a glorified unzip program.

### Sidenote: Where does the installer get 5GB of data from 200MB of archives if not the Internet?

That's high, though there are plenty of ways you could get that compression ratio. Imagine a complex game whose world is defined in verbose XML -- that's readily compressible. You could even get that back in the old WinZIP days.

Answer (score 1):

A zip file can only hold some files and then you unzip and get those files as is.

An installer however can be a very complicated program. It can create the needed files or folders structures, It can register the required dlls on your system, give you the options of the features that can be installed, Check your system for the compatibility and also be used as a wizard to guide you, step by step, to custom install you application.

Answer (score 0):

An Installer (esp. Windows Installer) can make automatic Registry entries, as well as unpack and write files to a directory. With the Zip, you have to manually extract the files, and get no automatic registry edits.

The advantage to a zip is that it guarantees (most of the time) that the application is portable, that all necessary files are included in the unzipped directory.

The advantage of an installer is pretty obvious: automated, UI.

As for the 200mb -> 5gb....compressing the files into an exe can add another layer of more/better/smaller compression than that of just simply throwing the files into a zipped folder, however 200mb -> 5gb is a pretty big jump, not impossible, just pretty big.  For most installers that do have instructions for large external (online) downloads, they typically let you know before hand that they are about to download a large chunk of data and to not disconnect from the internet during install....

Answer (score 0):

A standalone zip might be pretty helpful if you are unsure of your OS condition. For example - Like in Schools and colleges we have system that easily get corrupted so standalone files are more preferred so they can stored separately from OS. As for installers they are more suitable for the better performance as all registry and environment are are created by itself. As a developer I preferred for standalone software because they are portable too. But might be painful in not handle properly.

Answer (score -1):

An Installer or EXE Can Be Easily Get Affected By Virus But if there is ZIP archive than there are less chances for virus affection and using zip is more flexible too because it can be protected using you own password too.
Another Normal Benefit is that ZIP compress the files too.
Hope You are getting me.